# If $f \in L^2(\mathbb T)$ then $S_n(f) \to f$ in $L^2$ sense.

Tags: fourier-analysis, proof-verification, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

**Theorem**: If $f \in L^2(\mathbb T)$, then $S_n(f) \to f$ in $L^2(\mathbb T)$ sense.

**Proof**: Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb T)$, then by definition $\|f\|_2^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \vert f(x) \vert^2 \, dx < \infty$.

We want to show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \|f - S_n(f)\|_2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \vert f(x) - S_n(f)(x) \vert^2 \, dx = 0.$$

Since $\{e_k\}$ is a complete orthonormal set where $e_k = e^{ikx}$, then we can write $$f(x) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k = \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \widehat f(k) e^{ikx}.$$

Notice that $\displaystyle S_n(f)(x) = \sum_{k = -n}^n \widehat f(k) e^{ikx}$, so $\vert f(x) - S_n(f)(x) \vert \to 0$ and moreover $\vert f(x) - S_n(f)(x) \vert^2 \to 0$.

Notice that $\vert f(x) - S_n(f)(x) \vert^2 \leq \vert f(x) \vert^2$. We use the Dominated Convergence Theorem with $\vert f(x) \vert^2$ as our dominating function and conclude that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi} \vert f(x) - S_n(f)(x) \vert^2 \, dx = \int_0^{2\pi} \lim_{n \to \infty} \vert f(x) - S_n(f)(x) \vert^2 \, dx = \int_0^{2\pi} 0 \, dx = 0.$$

Conclude that $S_n(f) \to f$ in the $L^2$ sense. $\square$

Is this reasoning correct? If not, how would one prove this?

Comment: If $e_k$ are a complete orthonormal set then you know that $\|f-\sum_k \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k \| = 0$. Since $\|S_n(f)-\sum_k \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k \| \to 0$, it follows from the triangle inequality that $\|f-s_n(g)\| \to 0$. In your proof, you need to justify the pointwise convergence of $S_n(f)(x)$.

Comment: You have a line: "Since $\|S_n(f) - \sum_k \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k \| \to 0$, it follows...", but isn't that what I'm trying to prove, since $f = \sum_k \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k$?

Comment: No, you are trying to prove that $S_n(f) \to f$. But you know that $\|f-\sum_k \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k \| = 0$ by completeness, and Bessel's inequality gives $\sum_k |\langle f, e_k \rangle|^2 \le \|f\|^2$, so you know that $S_n(f) \to \sum_k \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k $ (in $L_2$).

Comment: My point is that you don't need to fiddle with pointwise convergence (which is harder to establish, and you haven't established).

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not seeing how Bessel's inequality is being used to show that $S_n(f) \to \sum_k \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k$ (in $L^2$?

Comment: @cooper.hat, Parseval's identity tells us that $\|f\|^2 = \sum_k \vert \langle f, e_k \rangle \vert^2 \geq \sum_{k = -n}^n \vert \langle f, e_k \rangle \vert^2$ for any natural number $n$. I now want to show that $\|S_n(f) - f\| = \|S_n(f) - \sum_k \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k \| = \int_{\mathbb T} \vert S_n(f)(x) - \sum_k \langle f(x), e_k(x) \rangle e_k(x) \vert^2 \, dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. How does this follow from looking at Pareseval/Bessel?

Comment: You have $\|S_n(f)-\sum_k \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k \|^2 = \| \sum_{|k|>n} \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k \|^2 = \sum_{|k|>n} |\langle f, e_k \rangle|^2$. The Bessel inequality shows that the latter term goes to zero.

Comment: As an aside, the fact that $S_n(f)(x) \to f(x)$ ae. is known as Carleson's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning is valid except that the pointwise convergence of $S_n(f)$ was not shown. This follows from [Carleson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem).

Here's a different approach.

**Theorem**: Suppose $\{e_k\}$ is an orthonormal set in (infinite dimensional) Hilbert space $H$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. The span of $\{e_k\}$ is dense in $H.$
2. $\{e_k\}$ is a maximal orthonormal set.
3. If $\langle x,e_k\rangle=\langle y,e_k\rangle$ for all $k,$ then $x=y.$
4. $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$ for all $x\in H.$
5. *Parseval's Identity*: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2=\|x\|^2$ for all $x\in H.$

A set $\{e_k\}$ satisfying these conditions is called a complete orthonormal set.

**Theorem**: If we define $e_k$ in $L^2(\mathbb T)$ by $e_k(x) = e^{ikx}$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$, then $\{e_k\}$ is a complete orthonormal set.

**Theorem**: If $f \in L^2(\mathbb T)$, then $S_n(f) \to f$ in $L^2(\mathbb T)$ sense.

**Proof**: Since $f \in L^2$ and $\{e_k\}$ is complete in $L^2$, then $f = \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k$. Observe that
$$
\begin{align*}
\|S_n(f) - f\|_2^2 &= \bigg \|\sum_{k = -n}^n \vert \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k  - \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k \bigg \|_2^2 \\
&= \bigg \| \sum_{\vert k \vert > n} \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k \bigg \|^2 \\
&\leq \sum_{\vert k \vert > n} \vert \langle f, e_k \rangle \vert^2
\end{align*}
$$
Since  $\|f\|^2 = \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \vert \langle f, e_k \rangle \vert^2 < \infty$, then $\sum_{\vert k \vert > n} \vert \langle f, e_k \rangle \vert^2 \to 0$.

Conclude that $S_n(f) \to f$ in the $L^2$ sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are two facts related to $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ that you will use:

1. $(e_n)_n$ is an orthonormal system - easy
2. The span of $(e_n)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$. This is proved using a generic result about the density of continuous functions in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ and the Weierstrass approximation with trigonometric polynomials ( linear combinations of $e_n$'s ) for continuous functions on $\mathbb{T}$.

There is a third very general fact that is valid for (pre)Hilbert spaces ( completeness is not required for this):

3. Let $(e_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ an orthonormal system in $H$, $I$  finite subset of indexes in  $\mathbb{Z}$ and $v$ in $H$. For every $(b_n)_{n \in I}$ a system of coefficients we have the inequality (best approximation):

$$|| v - \sum_{n \in I} \langle v, e_n \rangle  e_n||\le ||v - \sum_{i \in I} b_n e_n||$$

Indeed we have the equality:

$$|| v - \sum_{n \in I} \langle v, e_n \rangle  e_n||^2 + || \sum_{n \in I }(\langle v, e_n \rangle - b_n) \cdot e_n ||^2 = ||v - \sum_{i \in I} b_n e_n||^2$$

by Pythagoras.

The $L^2$ convergence ( even in generalized sense) of the Fourier series is easy now. Take any $\epsilon >0$. There exists a finite  $I_{\epsilon}  \subset \mathbb{Z}$ and  a linear combination of $(e_n)_{n\in I}$ that approximates $f$ better than $\epsilon$ (from $2$.):

$$ || f - \sum_{n \in I_{\epsilon} } b_n e_n||< \epsilon$$

Take any $I$ finite, $I \supset I_{\epsilon}$. By the $3$. above we have

$$|| f - \sum_{i \in I} \langle f, e_n \rangle \cdot e_n|| < \epsilon$$